# Selecting css components during yeoman initialization, twitter bootstrap and angular

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to use angular, yeoman, and sass at the same time, also I only wanted some css components in twitter bootstrap, so I tried scaffolding my app like this

```
yo angular --coffee
```

And answered yes for the following questions,

> would you like to install twitter bootstrap & would you like to use compass sass blah2x.

I answered yes,

Now the application is ready to go, but I have few concerns.

1. it loads all twitter bootstrap components, I actually wanted only the normalize.scss

How do I selectively use an scss component, because it builds all files, making my codebase super big because of unnecessary imports.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you may need  `yeoman install yeoman-normalize.scss` and then inside your `main.scss` file add a import line to correctly add `normalize.scss`

So:

```
@import "../components/yeoman-normalize.scss/yeoman-normalize";
```